# Expressing a matrix as a product

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $PL = L^TP$ where $P$ is a diagonal matrix.

How can I show that $L$ can be decomposed as $L = P^{-1}Q$ for some symmetric matrix $Q$?

I left multiplied by the inverse of $P$ to get $L = P^{-1}L^TP$ and tried to define $Q$ as the product of the transpose of $L$ and $P$, but I cannnot show it's symmetric. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you know what $(L^T P)^T$ equals?

Comment: Yeah it's $P^TL$

Comment: @gks Right, now notice that $P^T=P$

Comment: Oh I see it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that for matrices $A,B$, whenever the product $AB$ is defined, we have
$$
(AB)^T = B^TA^T.
$$

Comment: Was the transpose supposed to go outside the parentheses?

Comment: @gks Yes, fixed it